# Select a random set of rows without any duplicates

Tags: php

**How can I display a random set of questions (pulled from Wordpress) without any duplicates?**

This is what I've tried:

```
<?php 
$amount = get_field('select_number_of_questions');
$rand_max = count(get_field('step_by_step_test')) -1;
$rand = rand($amount,$rand_max); 
$i = 0;

while(has_sub_field('step_by_step_test')):
    if($rand == $i):
        echo the_sub_field('question');
    endif;
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

At the moment it just shows 1 random question.

It's all dynamic so for instance there can be a total of 10, 20, 31 questions etc. The total amount of questions to select is defined by `get_field('select_number_of_questions');`

`count(get_field('step_by_step_test')) -1;` is getting the total amount of questions to select from.

So in conclusion I want it to select the amount of questions defined by `get_field('select_number_of_questions');` from a total of `count(get_field('step_by_step_test')) -1;` without any duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure about how to specifically implement this in WordPress, but this is how your workflow should look like:

1. Take all of the questions into an array.
2. Select one question in random (using `array_rand()`).
3. Remove that question from the array (using `unset($array[$question_you_selected])`).
4. Select again.
5. Rinse and repeat until you have the number of questions you want. You won't have duplicates.

Comment: Ok I've solved the first part with your theory (thanks). Just the second part to the question to solve.

Comment: Second part? What second part?

Comment: Sorry I've now added that as a separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638373/include-required-questions-in-a-random-selection