# Include "required questions" in a random selection

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm selecting a set of random questions without any duplicates using the following:

```
<?php
$amount = get_field('select_number_of_questions');
$repeater = get_field("step_by_step_test");
shuffle($repeater);
$repeater_limit = array_slice($repeater,0,$amount);
foreach($repeater_limit as $repeater_row) {
    echo "<p>".$repeater_row['question']."</p>";
    $rows = $repeater_row['answer_options'];
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo $row['answer']."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Each question has a field: `get_field('required_question');` that has a yes/no dropdown. The questions that have yes selected ALWAYS have to be incorporated into the loop above.

E.g The test has 20 questions to select from, 10 will be selected at random. Within the 20 questions, there are 2 required questions (i.e these will always be selected). So it will need to grab the 2 required questions and select 8 other random questions.

**How can I include the required questions within the random selection?**

Comment: How are the questions connected with the `required` field? Can we see the form?

Comment: As I can see it's an array of questions, so you can simply request the required questions & add them to the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Question doesn't state it, but all suggests this is an [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) set up using the [Repeater Add-on](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/).

In that case, this is the test configuration I've done:

[image: acf config]

Note that here I'm using `$repeater_row['title']` instead of the OP's `$repeater_row['question']`. Also, I removed the `answer_options` part. See comments for details:

```
// Get fields
$amount = get_field( 'select_number_of_questions' );
$repeater = get_field( 'step_by_step_test' );

// Auxiliary arrays to separate fields by Field Name
$not_enabled = array();
$enabled = array();

// Separate
foreach( $repeater as $field )
{
    if( 'no' == $field['enabled'] )
        $not_enabled[] = $field;
    else
        $enabled[] = $field;
}

// Discount the enabled from the the total amount
$amount = (int)$amount - count( $enabled );

// Shuffle before slicing
shuffle( $not_enabled );
$repeater_limit = array_slice( $not_enabled, 0, $amount );

// Add enabled fields and shuffle again
$final_array = array_merge( $repeater_limit, $enabled ); 
shuffle( $final_array );

foreach( $final_array as $repeater_row ) {
    echo "<p>" . $repeater_row['title'] . "</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to filter out the required questions like so:

```
$all_questions = get_field("step_by_step_test");
$required = $optional = array();
foreach($all_questions as $question) {
    if( $a['required_question']) $required[] = $question;
    else $optional[] = $question;
}
$amount = get_field("select_number_of_questions")-count($required);
shuffle($optional);
$final = array_merge($required,array_slice($optional,0,$amount));
foreach($final as $repeater_row) {
    ...
}
```

Hope I helped you again :p

Comment: I've made an edit to your answer, it includes the correct required field code now but it still doesn't include the 2 required questions in the 5 randomly selected.

Comment: `get_field("required_question")` isn't specifying which question. I'm not sure I understand how your `get_field` function works...

Comment: get_field("required_question") is just grabbing whether the question in Wordpress is required or not (the dropdown can be yes or no). That's why I thought it needed something like if(get_field("required_question") == "Yes"). I guess just treat it as a variable that can have yes or no values.

Comment: Did you try to modify if( $a['required_question']) $required[] = $question; to something like if( strtolower($question['required_question']) == 'yes') $required[] = $question;