# Matching up two foreach loops using array value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two foreach loops. The first grabs a load of questions from Wordpress, the second is supposed to grab the multiple answers. This is straight forward had it not involved some randomisation of the questions, which makes it confusing.

This is the two foreach loops without them being randomised.

```
<?php 
$repeater = get_field('step_by_step_test');
foreach( $repeater as $repeater_row ){ ?>
    <p><?php echo $repeater_row['question']; ?></p>
    <?php $rows = $repeater_row['answer_options'];
    foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
        <?php echo $row['answer']; ?><br />
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This loops through each question and also grabs the multiple answers.

How can I incorporate it randomising the questions? This is my attempt, this works for getting a random set of questions but I'm getting an error for the answers part (invalid argument supplied for foreach).

```
<?php 
$amount = get_field('select_number_of_questions');
$repeater = get_field('step_by_step_test');
$random_rows = array_rand( $repeater, $amount );
echo implode(', ', $random_rows);
    foreach( $random_rows as $repeater_row ){ ?>
        <p><?php echo $repeater[$repeater_row]['question']; ?></p>
        <?php $rows = get_sub_field('answer_options');
        foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
            <?php echo $row['answer']; ?><br />
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

I use this plugin for wordpress - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: Your approach looks good, the error is probably because `get_sub_field` is not returning an array, probably worth checking in there

Comment: @mattedgod I've tried several ways but just get the same error - `has_sub_field`, `get_field`, `get_sub_field`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'm going to rewrite your first code block to not look like chewed cud.

```
<?php
$repeater = get_field("step_by_step_test");
foreach($repeater as $repeater_row) {
    echo "<p>".$repeater_row['question']."</p>";
    $rows = $repeater_row['answer_options'];
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo $row['answer']."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

And now for the magic: Add `shuffle($rows)` immediately before the `foreach($rows as $row) {` line, and the answers will appear in random order.

EDIT in response to comments: Start your code like this:

```
$repeater = get_field("step_by_step_test");
shuffle($repeater);
$repeater_limit = array_slice($repeater,0,5);
foreach($repeater_limit as $repeater_row) {
    ....
```

Comment: Maybe it's the way I've worded it all. I don't want to randomise the answers. I want it to randomise the questions (which it does) - and show the answers for those questions. The system currently grabs 5 random questions from 20, not just randomising the order of 20 questions. As mentioned in the question, I get an invalid argument for the second foreach.

Comment: Well, try `shuffle($repeater)` right before the first `foreach`

Comment: Again, that won't limit the amount of questions. Like I said, there's 20 questions and I want to grab 5 random questions from that 20.

Comment: Thanks, that worked... ironically the original randomising code was a suggestion from the plugin creator!

Comment: Since you bossed that question I have a related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638373/include-required-questions-in-a-random-selection. I have some questions that HAVE to be included in the random selection.